# Should i try to avoid using the Remote validation attribute to check the for existence of i record for performance issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I have a case in my application where no two records should have the same Assessment name. To do so i am implementing this rule using the Remote validation attribute for both client and server side validation. As follow:-

```
[Remote("CheckAssessmentName", "Assessment")]
[Required]
public string AssessmentName { get; set; }
```

```
public JsonResult CheckAssessmentName(string AssessmentName)
{
    var c = elearningrepository.checkname(AssessmentName).Count() == 0;
    return Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The problem is that the client side validation will be triggered each time the user insert or delete a character in the Assessment name field ,, so i am afraid that this will cause a performance issue assuming that i might have hundreds of assessment records, so should i use my current approach or there is a better way to do this?

Second question can i disable the client side validation for this specific Remote validation attribute for that i will only check the existence of the assessment name only on the server !!?
BR

Comment: Cache is your friend. Besides, look at sites like Twitter that do that exact thing when checking for username availability. The requests can be quite insignificant if you approach it correctly. For example. If a user's first letter is "a" then fetch and cache the "a" records and store them with an "a" key. If they then change to "b", do the same for be records. Cache what you can while NOT fetching the entire table.

Comment: Another approach would be to simply not call the CheckAssessmentName until after the `input` loses focus. In my personal opinion, the Remote Validation feature when used correctly is a GREAT tool.

Comment: THE client side validation will first work only when the input loses focus for the first time ,, but after moving the focus then the client side error will occur even if the user still typing!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one can answer this for you without knowing your server stats, what else is running, network perf , query with or without indexes etc

Try it, just remember you have to check on the server side as well since remote validation does not automatically Validate again when you save your form meaning if JavaScript is off( or scripts havent loaded before they submit the form) then they can bypass the checks

Comment: thanks for your reply; but the [Remote("CheckAssessmentName", "Assessment")] and other annotation validation such as required,rang,etc, will by default perform both client and server side validation ,, i have read this . and if i disable the client side validation inside my application <add key=”ClientValidationEnabled” value="false""> then these errors will still be displayed after pressing the submit button, so they will be default perform server side validation...

Comment: [Remote()] as of mvc3 does not include a working server validation piece. The other annotations do, Remote() does not. I (and others) have validated this and been unable to get it to work for server side validation even though the docs allude to it. The other data annotations work fine on the server side, remote does not. In fact: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-server-side-remote-validation